# IONIC 3 - How to check a possible problem with an plugin?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've an Ionic 3 app that's working fine when compiled without --prod flag (debug mode). When I set the --prod, the app stops on splash screen.

This works (the app open normal):

> ionic cordova run android

This works too:

> ionic cordova build android

This doesn't works (the app stops on splash screen):

> ionic cordova build android --minifyjs --minifycss --release --aot

Neither this command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

This is the only information I've when use `adb logcat`

```
$ adb logcat| grep CONSOLE
12-30 06:47:39.312 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(4062)] "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (4062)
12-30 06:47:39.968 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1233)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1233)
12-30 06:47:39.969 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1226)] "Channel not fired: onPluginsReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1226)
12-30 06:47:39.969 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1226)] "Channel not fired: onCordovaReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1226)
12-30 06:47:39.970 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(186993)] "Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (186993)
12-30 06:47:40.236 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js (3)
12-30 06:47:41.334 20569 20569 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(186988)] "Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 13596 ms", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (186988)
```

I've tried to debug on production mode changing the `build.grandle` file, without success:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

This is my ionic info:

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.12.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 26 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.8.1
   native-run                             : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/diego/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.20.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.10
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

My cordova plugin list output:

```
$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.3 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.2.0 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 4.1.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.7.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-photo-library 2.2.1 "Photo Library"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player 1.0.6 "CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer"
cordova-support-google-services 1.4.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
in.lucasdup.bringtofront 0.0.1 "Bring to Front"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.5 "Launch Navigator"
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks you.

Comment: According to **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945213/firebaseerror-messaging-this-browser-doesnt-support-the-apis-required-to-use)** this error can be solved by using the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` plugin instead if that's possible based on your project's requirements.

Comment: @sebaferreras ty for your comment, but it's not a Firebase problem. The app was working fine with this warning about sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get this working again!

For anyone get in trouble using ionic 3 + firebase, this is my working setup:

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-lib": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "7.14.2",
    "firebase-config": "0.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
},

"devDependencies": {
   "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
   "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
},
```

ionic info

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 27 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/diego/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.10
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

Thank you!